# Open ID ConnectにおいてIDトークンが盗まれる可能性について

Tags: oauth

Open ID Connectについて勉強中です。
Client = WEBブラウザ、RP = WEBサーバー、OP = Googleなどが提供しているプラットフォーム、を想定しています。

[この](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/openidconnectintroseptember2013-131010025559-phpapp02/95/openid-connect-20139-8-638.jpg?cb=1381391826)Implicitフローをベースに質問させてください。

このフローを実装しているサイトをサイトAとします。悪意のあるサイトをサイトBとします。
サイトAのサービスを利用するユーザーが、悪意のあるサイトBにアクセスしてしまったとします。そこでそのサイトBにおいて、サイトAのログイン用APIに意図せずアクセスさせられてしまい（フローでいうと0番目）、その後、フローの５番目までを実行されてしまい、IDトークンを盗まれてしまう可能性はないのでしょうか？（クロスドメイン制約があるので無理？）
私はIDトークンに含まれるnonceというものの役割を理解していないので、このような質問をしているのかもしれません。nonceというランダムな値がサイトAのサーバーで作成され、その後、OPから帰ってくるIDトークンにも含まれるということは理解しているのですが、それが上述したIDトークンが盗まれてしまった場合にどう機能するのかがわかりません。

混乱の中での質問となり、要領を得ない質問で申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

懸念されているフローは、
1. ユーザーは意図せずメールや様々な手段でサイトBに誘導された
2. サイトBは"サイトAになりすまし"、OPの認可画面を要求するリクエストを送る
3. ユーザーは"サイトAに対して"自分の情報に対するアクセスを許可
4. ユーザーはサイトBに戻され、ID Tokenを取得される
というような認識であっていますでしょうか？

基本的に、意図しない戻り先URLにユーザーが戻されるかどうかは、OPのclient管理の実装に依存します。
OPへ送られるリクエストのパラメータにclient_id, redirect_uriの値が含まれています。
RPがOPに事前にアプリケーションを登録するのが一般的であり、この際にredirect_uriを設定します。
OPによりその組み合わせの検証が正しく行われ、OPがユーザーをサイトAにのみ戻すような実装が必要となります。

ここでサイトA側が気を付けることとしては、
* OPに対して必要最小限なURLのみをredirect_uriに登録する
* redirect_uriがオープンリダイレクタとして動作しないようにする(client_id, redirect_uriの検証が行われてもサイトBに誘導される可能性がある)
というあたりです。

ID Tokenの検証に関しては、どちらかというと、サイトAに戻るリクエスト(仕様ではAuthentication Response)を検証することが目的となります。
1. 悪意のあるユーザーが自らのID Tokenをパラメータに付与したURLを生成し、別のユーザーにアクセスさせる
2. サイトAはID Tokenの検証を行って、不正なリクエストをはじく
という流れです。こちらの詳細について気になる場合は、別途説明します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。フローはまとめていただいたフローをまさに想定しておりました。ご回答の中にあるオープンリダイレクタに関する注意を読んで気づいたのですが、私のリダイレクトに関する認識が誤っておりました。XMLHttpRequestでリダイレクトのステータスコードを受け取った際に、リダイレクトを阻止できるものと思っておりました。調べたところ、間違いだと気づきました。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228225/prevent-redirection-of-xmlhttprequest　基本的なところの知識不足で申し訳ありませんでした。しかしその上で、オープンリダイレクタとして動作しないようにするというのが、どういう実装なのかまだ理解できていないので、自分で調べてみようと思います。